# How to get MD5 from debug.keystore file?

Tags: android

I use some command to get MD5 private key from `debug.keystore` file but actually I get SHA1 private key instead of MD5. I do not know how to get MD5.

This is command that I use.

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore (path_to_debug_keystore).keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: It seems the v1.7 JDK is showing SHA1 by default instead of MD5 (I don't remember having this problem on my old PC).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to obtain Signing certificate fingerprint (SHA1) for OAuth 2.0 on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214467/how-to-obtain-signing-certificate-fingerprint-sha1-for-oauth-2-0-on-android)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When I did it I used this.

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android -v
```

Looks like your keystore file isn't correct.

Comment: please add the -v option for future reference. This answer isn't correct, as it only replicates what the OP tried. Also, his file wasn't incorrect, because debug.keystore has more than one fingerprint. I really don't understand why this is the "correct" answer.

Comment: This answer is obsolete, the "-v" option [no more prints MD5](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8249541) for JDK 8 and newer.

Answer (score 43):

Try to simply add a ***-v*** to your command. Then you will get fingerprints in *MD5*, *SHA1* and *SHA256*.
The MD5 one should be accepted by Google API Signup. =)

Comment: This is still not giving MD5 in the results, I am only getting SHA1 and SHA256.

Answer (score 22):

You do not need to downgrade your jdk!

You should add '-v' to your keytool command, as already suggested.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

This is because you are using jdk7 which, unlike jdk6, does not print the MD5 certificate fingerprint by default.

The android [documentation](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html) does not mention this (as per postdate)

Comment: but mine is turning into Runtime Exceptions.

Comment: This answer worked, but prompted me for a password.  The password (as noted in other answers) is "android"

Comment: My command is : keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepas
s android -keypass android , but it is not returning MD5, but only SHA1 and SHA256.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks everyone. Now i got my MD5 private key. I used JDK7. 
For your reference,

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool.exe -list -v -keystore "C:\Documents
and Settings\Administrator\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass
android
```

Comment: This command does not give the MD5, only the defaults that is 'SHA'.

Answer (score 3):

you have the right sintaxis, be sure where is your keystore file located...

this is my example:

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\jorgesys\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

and the result must be something like...

```
androiddebugkey, 25/09/2010, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5):
32:46:AA:56:D9:71:8B:2A:0B:34:A1:B6:96:1E:87:59
```

if you don't remember your user and password you will create another keystore...

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore "C:\android\gruporeforma.keystore" -alias gruporeforma -keyalg RSA -validity 10000
```

Comment: This is my command ---> (keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\user\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android)                                                                                      but I still get SHA1 private key

Comment: This is still not giving MD5 in the results, I am only getting SHA1 and SHA256.

Answer (score 2):

**This will help you definately. Please refer this screen shot.....**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse or ADT you can go to Preferences -> Android -> Build and there you will see your debug keystore MD5 and SHA1 fingerprints.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your are currently in `jdk/bin` in your terminal

For Linux or OS X, open a terminal window and enter the following:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

For Windows Vista and Windows 7, run:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

If you are successful in above step you will get:

```
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Jan 01, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 4aa9b300
Valid from: Mon Jan 01 08:04:04 UTC 2013 until: Mon Jan 01 18:04:04 PST 2033
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  AE:9F:95:D0:A6:86:89:BC:A8:70:BA:34:FF:6A:AC:F9
     SHA1: BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:07:71:9B:62:90:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3
```

Comment: In my case the output is not giving MD5:

Comment: Valid from: Mon Apr 30 12:59:46 IST 2018 until: Wed Apr 22 12:59:46 IST 2048
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: 75:B9:88:AF:D3:E3:_:1B:40:B1:61:0D:4A:FF:35:B9:_:CD:7B:28
         SHA256: C4:87:91:E1:DD:E5:B2:_:57:D0:DE:C7:1D:6D:E2:87:94:_:4A:20:EB:AB:99:73:74:B7:12:EB:04:AD:9E:5A
Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena do you have Android Studio installed right now? If yes open your project; at the right side click `Gradle > Your project > Tasks > Android > signingReport` and it will show similar thing above.

Comment: Yes it is working there. But what is the command it must be issuing there?

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena I can't answer that sorry.

Comment: In the output using my command line, it is showing version as 1 in the last line.  In yours it is 'version: 3'.

Comment: I don't know how to produce the version code but if I remember correctly I am using OpenJDK.

Comment: It is not working: on my console, where the version is --> java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem use java jdk6 not jdk7 ... work for me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone. I can generate my MD5 private key.
I know the some problem. If I use java version 7, I will get SHA1 but when I downgrade java version such as jdk1.6, I will also get MD5.

Comment: This is still not giving MD5 in the results, I am only getting SHA1 and SHA256.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that answer in the link:

[How to get 'MD5' instance from keystore instead of 'SHA' ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52620996/787399)

Reason being, in the other answers, the command line is used to get the `SHA`, `MD5`, but a program can elaborate to explicitly get the `MD5` instance from a signature. In the above case, you are specifying `SHA`, hence you will get `SHA` only.

Happy Coding :-)