# Android App with Google map not displaying

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I recently inherited an Android app project here at work. The app works fine when plugged into the person-who-I-inherited-the-project-from's computer but when plugged into my computer the portion with a google map is blank and I get a "Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors)." error in my console. This leads me to believe it's a setup issue on my end but after pouring over google and stackoverflow for many hours the problem persists.

I'm using ADT bundle 22. On Ubuntu 12.04. I added the google-play-services-lib through the sdk manager. My project's build path looks like this [image: goole-play-services-lib] and the "Order and Export" tab looks like this [image: order]

I also created a new api key at https://code.google.com/apis/console/ and ensured that "Google Maps Android API v2" was selected. I added this key to the AndroidManifest.xml in the appropriate location.

After multiple fresh imports of the project source and multiple fresh installs of the ADT, my problem remains. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does the project you took over use Google Maps Android V2 or the old version of Google Maps? Also you said you have created a new api key, have you added your signing certificate SHA1 with the package name as allowed Android apps for that key?

Comment: I used the SHA1 from my /.android/debug.keystore and my package name, yes. It is the v2 of google maps

Comment: Try removing all certificates from your key in the API Console (leave to `Any app allowed`). This is not a solution but may point you to the right direction.

Comment: can you post your Manifest.xml? it feels like you forgot one of the permissions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a flyer I refreshed my key and changed the part with **com.mycompany** to **com.mycompany.packagename**. Maybe this was common knowledge but as the google help associated with key creation as show below only included **com.mycompany** I feel it is misleading. Maybe this can help somebody else.
[image: googlehelp]

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem becouse of **credentials (Google MAP API key)**
You need to generate new API key by using you machine's **SHA1 finger print**

Eclipse, if you go to Windows -> Preferences -> Android -> Build you find SHA1 fingerprint

copy that key and generate new API key

for referense read this ->
[How to obtain Signing certificate fingerprint (SHA1) for OAuth 2.0 on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214467/how-to-obtain-signing-certificate-fingerprint-sha1-for-oauth-2-0-on-android)