# googlemapsv2 white screen

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I developed my first application [Turkiye trafik Olayları](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=turkiye.yollari.trafikolaylari&hl=tr).

My problem is that if I open my application in Eclipse with ether a real device or virtual device, Google maps v2 works perfectly. But if a user installs it, Google maps v2 appears only as a white screen. What could be the problem?

I can not find the problem because if I use debug with real device it works as expected (shows Google map).

Comment: have you signed your `apk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have added the correct credentials on the [Google API console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/334867713139/apiui/credential?authuser=1). Click the `Edit allowed Android applications` button and add the SHA1 and package name from your release keystore.

[image]

Chances are that you have setup credentials for your debug keystore so you can see the map while in development but there are no credentials for your release keystore. So when you make signed release builds the white screen shows instead of the map.

If you haven't already created a keystore for your release builds and retrieved the SHA1 you can learn how to do that from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214467/how-to-obtain-signing-certificate-fingerprint-sha1-for-oauth-2-0-on-android) question.

Comment: thanks for answer.After signed my application I copied sha1 fingerprint. on developper console i generete new key for this signed sha1. I have a question. Should i update my google api key on android manifest with this key? Because after I signed i newly learned new sha1.If i have to update again then i should again export application. My second question is that on status google developer console says Active until Mar 12, 2015 9:26 AM what will be done after that date?

Comment: You should only need to create an API key once, after that you can click Edit allowed Android applications and continue to add new SHA1;package_name entries. 

Yes, whatever API key is currently shown in the developer console should be added to your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a probleam of Key used in your app googlemapsv2, are you using the debug certificate key because that should only work testing as you sayed its working fine for production distribution you need to replace that key with your release distribution signing certificate.

Comment: yes i use key but dont know debug or signed.how to do that?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_the_api_key_to_your_application--->Displaying the release certificate fingerprint try reading that section

Comment: you have two sections in that page one for Displaying the debug certificate fingerprint, and the other for Displaying the release certificate fingerprint, at some point you must haved used the first one to get your key