# API keys causing issues

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

In my android app I am using google map and location services.So I generated API key on google developer console for my development work using SHA1 generated by making use of debug.keystore.It worked fine and google map worked perfectly. When I had to release the apk I signed apk following instructions at http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio.

When I tried to beta test the app, google map didn't work.Visiting the forums told me that I need to generate another google console API key using SHA1 generated by using keysotore which was created while signing the apk.I did same and replaced the key in androidmanifest.xml(So now my project on google console has two API keys,older one I used for development,and newly created one ). But when I regenerated apk and tried to run it on my personal device from android studio, map didn't work.Moreover when I replaced new key by old debug version of key in manifest file and tried to rerun app on my android device map still don't work.So now my older key is also not working while it was working fine before all these changes.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: You need to use the same Map API key but add the debug SHA1 *and* the release keystore SHA1 to the credentials of the Map API key

Comment: Thanks Ed.I did same and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the same API Key for your applications but you need to add both the debug and release credentials.

So you will end up with two entries in the android applications:

```
99:88:77:66:55:44:33:22:11:04:76:99:C3:2A:52:71:7C:64:EC:8B;com.package.app

99:88:77:66:55:44:33:22:11:1C:CC:33:D7:74:A2:49:5D:7D:BF:C6;com.package.app
```

You can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990846/googlemapsv2-white-screen/28991134#28991134) for help with the process of adding credentials for each keystore.