# Google Maps on Android Wear Emulator Shows up Gray?

Tags: android, wear-os

I set up an Android Wear emulator (latest version), enabled developer mode, enabled ADB debugging, forwarded the TCP port, connected to the emulator from my phone, set an emulator GPS location using Android Device Monitor... but I can't get Maps working. Neither Maps v2 in my app, nor the actual Google Maps app on the device works correctly. The map just shows gray. In the Google Maps app, controls (like zoom) appear when tapped, as normal. The exit button does not appear, however, and the map never changes from gray. How can this be fixed?

Comment: To clarify, it works fine on a real device--but not on the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

You probably haven't set up your API key correctly.
Here is google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/signup) for setting up a key on Android

Essentially, you need to use your keystore (debug or release) to find your SHA1 fingerprint, and enter it into the google developer's console. It will then make you an API key, which you can enter into the android manifest

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="KEY GOES HERE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the correct package name and SHA1 into the [Google Developer's Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)?

If the console is not aware of what applications are using your Google maps API keys then it will not show the map view.

For more information on adding the package name and SHA1 into the console, refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990846/googlemapsv2-white-screen/28991134#28991134).