# Get SHA1 fingerprint certificate in Android Studio for Google Maps

Tags: android, macos, google-maps, sha1

I want to get the SHA1 key from Android Studio on a Mac. From Eclipse it's simple, but I can't get this in Android Studio.

I have checked similar questions but didn't get any way to get that in MAC.

The SHA1 is different for signed and unsigned APK. Please mention the methods to get for both.

Comment: Easiest way to Get SHA-1 For Release and Debug mode android studio gradle. [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate/35308827#35308827)

Answer (score 231, accepted):

I got my Answer, it was quit simple.
Open Terminal, 
Type command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Press Enter: You will get the following info, and SHA1 can be seen there.

.....

Certificate fingerprints:

```
 MD5:  79:F5:59:................FE:09:D1:EC

 SHA1: 33:57:0A:C9:..................:91:47:14:CD

 SHA256: 39:AA:23:88:D6:...................33:DF:61:24:CB:17:47:EA:39:94:99
```

.......

Comment: can you show the complete cmd path where you executing this command

Comment: @AneesU I am writing above command on home directory when i open terminal.

Answer (score 51):

**Very easy and simply finding the SHA1 key for certificate in only android studio.**
You can use below steps:

```
A.Open Android Studio
B.Open Your Project
C.Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)
D.Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar, you will see List Gradle scripts of your Project)
E.Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List (root))
F.Click on Tasks
G.Click on android
H.Double Click on signingReport (You will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar)
```

**OR**

```
1.Click on your package and choose New -> Google -> Google Maps Activity
2.Android Studio redirect you to google_maps_api.xml
```

[image]

Comment: @Jai Yea this is the best and simple answer but how to do it for release version?

Comment: **Other way of file SHA1 key**

1.Click on your package and choose New -> Google -> Google Maps Activity

2. Android Studio redirect you to google_maps_api.xml

Answer (score 29):

All above answers are correct.

**But,Easiest and Faster way is below:**

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open Your Project
3. Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)
4. Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar, you will see
   List Gradle scripts of your Project)
5. Click on Your Project Name like MyProject(root)
6. Click on Tasks
7. Click on android
8. Double Click on signingReport
9. Wait for few seconds and you will get SHA1 and MD5 in Console Bar

[image]

If you are adding a **MapActivity** in your project than see this answer for SHA1.
[How to obtain Signing certificate fingerprint (SHA1) for OAuth 2.0 on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214467/how-to-obtain-signing-certificate-fingerprint-sha1-for-oauth-2-0-on-android/32558627#32558627)

Answer (score 10):

1. Go to your key directory / Folder.
2. Use following command in the terminal: `keytool -list -v -keystore <yourKeyFileName.withExtension> -alias <yourKeyAlias>`.
3. Enter Key Password entered at time of key creations.

**yourKeyAlias had given at time of creation of your key.**

Comment: Sorry But this didn't work its giving this error.

keytool -list -v -keystore keystorename.keystore -alias aliasname
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: keystorename.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: keystorename.keystore
 at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:742)
 at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:340)
 at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:333)

Comment: Of course you have to change "kestorename.keystore" to the actualname of your keystore file. Same applies for the aliasname.

Comment: I got it, thanks, but what should be location of keystore file in my hard drive .. ?

Answer (score 10):

Follow the below steps to get SHA1 fingerprint Certificate in Android Studio in 2.2v.

> Open Android Studio Open your Project Click on Gradle (From Right Side
> Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)
>
> Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar, you will see List
> Gradle scripts of your Project)
>
> Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List (root))
>
> Click on Tasks
>
> Click on Android
>
> Double Click on signing-report (You will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar)
> Then click this button: [image] (top left of
> the error log) and you will get your SHA1 key.

Answer (score 7):

The other way to get the SHA1 fingerprint instead of inputting a `keytool` command is to create dummy project and select the `Google Map Activity` in the `Add an activity module` and after the project is created you then open the `values->google_maps_api.xml` in that xml you'll see the SHA1 fingerprint of your android studio.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way in `Android Studio` like `Eclipse` **Windows -> Preferences -> Android -> Build**.

`Android Studio` signs your app in debug mode automatically when you run or debug your project from the IDE.

You may get using the following Command!!

```
keytool -list -v -keystore  ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Answer (score 5):

Type this is the Terminal
keytool -list -v -keystore  ~/.android/debug.keystore

It will ask you to enter the password
enter 'android'

Then you would get the details like the SHA1.

Answer (score 1):

[image: After clicking signingReport You will get SHA-1 finger certificate for your application]

After clicking signingReport You will get SHA-1 finger certificate for your application

I am here if you need any other help

Answer (score 1):

FOR PRODUCTION BUILD / LIVE BUILD sha key follow these steps

> Step 1 ) **Add release details in gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.devdeeds.com.yourapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
//Signing configurations for build variants "release"
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("F:/Development/myapp.jks")
            storePassword "231232das"
            keyAlias "myapp_rel"
            keyPassword "dasd333_das"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
    //link above defined configuration to "release" build type
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
}
```

> Step 2) **open gradle menu from right menu bar and then app > android** >
> signingReport

[image]

> Step 3) **Click on signingReport and see the magic**

[image]