# Is not recognise an an internal or external command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

Following error from cmd.

> C:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin is not recognise an an internal
>   or external command, operable program or batch file

Answer (score 1):

`C:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin` this is a directory . try `"C:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe"`

Comment: i want to get sha1 fingerpriint from cmd.but this error has occured

Comment: @PhanindraReddyVedikola you can generate hashcode like `CertUtil -hashfile "c:\some.file" SHA1`

Comment: Quick search turned up this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214467/how-to-obtain-signing-certificate-fingerprint-sha1-for-oauth-2-0-on-android) is this what your looking to do?

Comment: How can i use this code.please explain clearly Mr.npocmaka

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to set Java path in your Windows System, Try this
Close `cmd` and follow these steps

Open `environment Variables` in `System Variables` edit `PATH` and Paste this
`C:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;`

Now open `cmd` and type `javac` to check.