# Google Plus sign in android Application

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I have integrated GPlus Login in my app.It is working fine when I installed from eclipse.I have uploaded that app in playstore and when I downloaded that app from playstore and trying to login with Google It is showing an internal error occured.

So I want to know that is there any mistakes from my side before uploading in playstore ??

Comment: did you assigned signed key or still debug key?

Comment: How many months before you have been uploaded the App in Playstore ?

Comment: yesterday uploaded...@Naveen

Comment: where I need to assign signed key ??

Comment: Then it should work fine...Just add Key in Google Developer's API Console

Comment: Yah But why It is like this I am not getting..

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214467/how-to-obtain-signing-certificate-fingerprint-sha1-for-oauth-2-0-on-android

Comment: after create this signed SHA1 you have to go google console and re-create api key then replace it in your project wherever you used

Comment: Check this example http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/ @ss_mine

Answer (score 0):

Just make signed key not debug key
signed key required for login with google or facebook
in app downloaded from playstore