# Error when running google map layout on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

The google map doesn't load when i run the APK of google map layout with my key on Android Device. There is no cache to be removed and any sort of data to be removed. Please help!

In MapActivity.java:

```
LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker Sydney"));
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
```

[image: Android screenshot]

Comment: check your key. this is the only possible problem

Comment: how to get the key?

Comment: get it from google api console

Comment: how to know the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey it seems quite obvious from your problem that the issue us with the key.

There are many solutions available but they all are old.

You can go through the following steps to obtain your Key:

1. Go to [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com).
2. Create a new project.
3. Fill all the entries.
4. To get your SHA1 fingerprint go  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214467/how-to-obtain-signing-certificate-fingerprint-sha1-for-oauth-2-0-on-android).
5. After successfully creating you project now you have to enable all the API's separately.
6. Whichever API you have to enable go to that API and you have to enable it.

Hope this clarifies your problem.

Thank you