# Google API key isn't working

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

I am trying to program an android app to contain a google map.  I am sure my code is correct because I have checked it a million times and even copied and pasted working code from other people.  When I launch the app my app just has a bunch of gray squares.  I have tried the API key and the debug KEY.  
This is how I retrieve the API key from cmd:

```
 Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Gateway Owner>cd C:/

C:\>cd Program Files\Java

C:\Program Files\Java>cd jdk1.7.0_02

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02>cd bin

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -
keystore "C:\Users\Gateway Owner\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -ke
ypass android
androiddebugkey, Feb 10, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): A5:18:02:AD:2E:C6:0E:02:C5:0A:F6:17:70:5E:31:1A:
AD:A8:81:FA

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin>
```

I have seen other screen shots and where I have (SHA1) in parenthesis other people have MD5.  Also I have noticed the command prompt gives me a 24 character long number where other people receive 16, and code.google only accepts a 16.  I'm starting to feel as though I need to decrypt my MD5 key or something... Please HELP!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following command to get md5,

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin>keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Gateway Owner\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 0):

Each project have individual keystore. First of all create new keystore for your project use that keystore. Again create MD5 u will get new key.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

to Follow my blog it's shows how to integrate google maps in android below link,

http://blog.360i.in/2012/10/19/google-maps-integration-with-android-sdk-on-windows/

and you can get md5 key below command it's worked perfectly for me

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey –keystore C:\Users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this answer (one with 23 upvotes
): [How to get MD5 from debug.keystore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262695/how-to-get-md5-from-debug-keystore-file)

You will learn more about it.
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

-v provided me with the MD5.  Than you everyone!

Comment: You should mark one of the answers that suggested the `-v` flag as the solution