# convert my application into .apk file it will not show google map

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

Hi i am new to android application development. I did a google map v2 to show my current location using GPS.

> It will work fine when i testing with mobile using USB cable
>   but the issue is when i convert my application into .apk it will retrive my gps current >location but did not show the map

Can anyone help to resolve my problem?

Comment: you have create a signed apk with release key. not the debug key.

Comment: Santhosh@ how to get signed apk release key..help me to get this one santhosh

Answer (score 2):

for generation .APK you must have to use `keystore` & `MAP API KEY` from same machine. if this two are diffrent from diffrent machine then it 'll heppend.. `(mean MAP are not show)`

if you have diffrent keystore then you can get MAP API Key from Keystore.

check below links:

[How can I get the MD5 fingerprint from Java's keytool, not only SHA-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6305938/1168654)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5262845/1168654

**Edited**

open this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey#getdebugfingerprint):  follow steps on `"Getting the MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate"` then sign up from this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/maps-api-signup) :  after that use that map key in you code see what heppend.

Comment: Dhaval Sodha Parmar@ i correctly did all the things but still i got the same output(MY mobile does not show the map )

Comment: Dhaval Sodha Parmar@ friend this is for google map api version 1 but i need google map api 2..its need only SHA1 no only..i also got that

Comment: you got SHA-1?? then also get MAP API KEY?? m i right? then put tha map key in your code. run it. you must have to do this.. otherewise there is no simple way.. you have to check all step mannually..

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that either you do not have the Google Play Services referenced in the project properly or your device doesn't support it.

Please read the [Quick Start](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw) on how to properly reference the jar in your project.

Comment: RyPope@ how to chek this one GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());