# Unable to display map in Android

Tags: android, dictionary

I want to display map in android emulator. For that i Installed Google play services and import  it in workspaces and make them references in my project. But i run application it shows Goolgle play services in not in Your phone. I am not able to understand why it shows. I am attaching full code here..
Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
     <uses-permission android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDcNgF68UPm1cNdlJmr41PGYG06z4P_NyI" />
    </application>

</manifest>

main.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>

.java file is here

package com.example.map;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
![enter image description here][1]
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

emulator image
Could you give me answer why it shows. It really help me.

Comment: If you go into Project -> Properties -> Android, is your build target a Google APIs target or an Android target?

Comment: Check this link it help me:



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262695/how-to-get-md5-from-debug-keystore-file/5262845#5262845
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305938/how-can-i-get-the-md5-fingerprint-from-javas-keytool-not-only-sha-1

Comment: in emulator google map doesn't show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Point 1.** Use below code if you are developing app for API level 8.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

see [MapFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html).
    Use this class only if you are targeting API 12 and above. Otherwise, use SupportMapFragment.

**Point 2.** Extend your class with **FragmentActivtiy** instead of **Activity**

private GoogleMap googleMap;

```
    public void loadGoogleMap(){
        if(googleMap==null){
              // Getting Google Play availability status
              int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
              // Showing status
              if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available
                  int requestCode = 10;
                  Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, (Activity)context, requestCode);
                  dialog.show();
              }else{
                // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
                  SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) this.YOUR_CLASS_NAME.getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.my_comm_nearme_map);

                  // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
                  googleMap = fm.getMap();

                  //setting map type
                  googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

                  UiSettings uiSettings = googleMap.getUiSettings();
                  uiSettings.setCompassEnabled(false);
                  uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                  uiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
              }
        }
    }
```

**Point 3.**

```
But i run application it shows Goolgle play services in not in Your phone.
```

Android need [Google Play services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en) in order to run maps. You can download it from market, and try again, Maps will work.

If you get error while installing [Google Play services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en) , then your device is not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Please go to google api and ON the Google Maps Android API v2 Only

Google API Console -> Service -> Google Maps Android API v2 ->

than generte new API Key and test.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to run customized google map on below api level-11 it also runs successfully on higher versions.

import google-play-services_lib project into your workspace from \sdk\extras\google\google_play_services_froyo\libproject .

right click to the project->properties->android->right click the check box in library panel name as "is library" and click apply and press ok.

now go to your projects property-android->in library panel->click add->now select "google-play-services_lib" in option->apply>ok

**Now use this code**

```
    package com.hmkcode.android;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

   import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            GoogleMap map;
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
                    19.233442, 72.980851), 16));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.house_flag))
                    .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f)
                    .position(new LatLng(19.233442, 72.980851))
                    .title("Hello world"));

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }

    }

}
```

**layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**in manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hmkcode.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
       />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.hmkcode.android.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="use your obtained key" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

now you can see the map else you will see button which can be used to update the services.