# Google map only show with device connect to my computer

Tags: android, google-maps

I create a project with google map API 2.0 and I showed map with devices connect to my computer. But, when I send code to my friends (via SVN) use another computer, he don't see map.
We use same device. (Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1) 
What's happen here? 
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your friend is running the code rather than an .APK you exported. This would mean that the application your friend is running will have a different SHA1 fingerprint.

You will have to make sure you added your friend's SHA1 fingerprint as well, in addition to your own. Add a new line to your existing Android Key in Google's API console with the new SHA1 and the same package name.

If you're using eclipse you can use go to Window > Preferences > Android > Build.

Alternatively, you can also follow the instructions as posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5262845/2675446